# Change date to string with month and day

Tags: php, sql

How can I change the current date format which is: YY/MM/DD to something like Oct 8th 2013.

This will be pulled straight from database.

Was not sure what to google in-order to find this.
Thanks.

Comment: Current date format in what? Do you want to display an SQL date in an HTML page?

Comment: [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: If you want to do it at the database level, your google search string is "your database engine date functions".

Comment: I wasn't really looking for comedic answers but thanks for the effort. @DanBracuk

Comment: The effort was not to be funny.  You said that you did not know how to google it.  You also failed to specify your database engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I linked in comments, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

And the resulting code would be something like:

```
$date = "13/10/08";
$tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat("y/m/d", $date);
echo $tmp->format("M jS Y");
```

Output:

```
Oct 8th 2013
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nxg-8ea)

Comment: Perfect. Others answered well however you provided an example so, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DateTime` class:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('y/m/d', '13/10/13');
if ( ! $time) {
    die('Date is invalid!');
}
echo $time->format('M jS Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql get current time:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %D %Y') FROM table;
```

or date format the exist time:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%b %D %Y) FROM table;
```